# How to use count() in must() clause in a YANG model?

Tags: xpath, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I tried to research this over the last few days but my research came up short, there seems not to be a lot of material out there on the use of the **must()** clause in a **YANG** model.

**Background**

I am trying to extend the NETCONF model of an I2RS YANG model (based on [IETF I2RS Data Model for Network Topologies](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-clemm-i2rs-yang-network-topo/?include_text=1)) with some customer-specific information. My model therefore augments the relevant parts of the model (shown in an abbreviated form here). Where I am stuck is formulating a proper way to implement some semantic contraints on the input data, specifically around the number of links that have a specific **link-usage**.
pyang is used as the toolchain for the following discussion.

**The augmenting YANG module**

The abbreviated module looks like this:

```
module bsc-topology {
yang-version 1;

namespace "urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:bsc:bsc-topology";

prefix "bsc";

import nodes {
    prefix "nd";
    revision-date 2015-03-09;
}

import network-topology {
    prefix "nt";
    revision-date 2015-03-09;
}

import ietf-inet-types {    
    prefix "inet";
}

organization "TBD";
contact "TBD";

revision "2015-03-11" {
    description "Initial revision";
    reference "TBD";
}

identity flag-identity {
    description "Base type for flags";
}

identity undefined-flag {
    base "flag-identity";
}

typedef bsc-link-service-type {
    type enumeration {
        enum "Ater" {
            value 1;
            description "This link describes the Ater topology";
        }
        enum "Gb" {
            value 2;
            description "This link describes the Gb topology";
        }
    }
}

typedef flag-type {

    type identityref {
        base "flag-identity";
    }
}

grouping ater-attributes {
    leaf prefix {
        type inet:ip-prefix;
    }
    leaf metric {
        type uint32;
    }
    leaf-list flag {
        type flag-type;
    }
}

grouping bsc-topology-type {
    container bsc-topology {
        presence "Indicates BSC Topology";
    }
}

grouping bsc-link-attributes {
    container bsc-link-attributes {
        leaf name {
            description "Link Name";
            type string;
        }

        leaf link-usage {
            type bsc-link-service-type;

            description "Type of Service described through this link (Ater or Gb)";

            must "boolean(count(../../../nd:link) = 1)";    
        }       
    }       
} 


augment "/nd:network/nd:network-types" {
    uses bsc-topology-type;
}

augment "/nd:network/nt:link" {
    when "/nd:network/nd:network-types/bsc-topology";
    uses bsc:bsc-link-attributes;
}
}
```

**The input file**

Trying to validate the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
      <nd:network xmlns:nd="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:nodes">
        <nd:network-id>Test</nd:network-id>
        <nd:network-types>
          <bsc:bsc-topology xmlns:bsc="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:bsc:bsc-topology"/>
        </nd:network-types>
        <nd:node>
          <nd:node-id>407201001A</nd:node-id>
          <nt:termination-point xmlns:nt="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:links">
            <nt:tp-id>SERVICE_TP</nt:tp-id>
          </nt:termination-point>
        </nd:node>
        <nd:node>
          <nd:node-id>407850001A</nd:node-id>
          <nt:termination-point xmlns:nt="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:links">
            <nt:tp-id>SERVICE_TP</nt:tp-id>
          </nt:termination-point>
        </nd:node>
        <nt:link xmlns:nt="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:links">
          <nt:link-id>407201001A-407850001A-Ater</nt:link-id>
          <nt:source>
            <nt:source-node>407201001A</nt:source-node>
            <nt:source-tp>SERVICE_TP</nt:source-tp>
          </nt:source>
          <nt:destination>
            <nt:dest-node>407850001A</nt:dest-node>
            <nt:dest-tp>SERVICE_TP</nt:dest-tp>
          </nt:destination>
          <bsc:bsc-link-attributes xmlns:bsc="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:bsc:bsc-topology">
            <bsc:link-usage>Ater</bsc:link-usage>
          </bsc:bsc-link-attributes>
        </nt:link>
      </nd:network>
    </config>
```

**Pyang validation output**

```
yang2dsdl -j -s -b nodes_network-topology_bsc-topology -t config -v foo3.xml
== Using pre-generated schemas

== Validating grammar and datatypes ...
foo3.xml validates.

== Adding default values... done.

== Validating semantic constraints ...
--- Failed assert at "/nc:config/nd:network/lnk:link/bsc:bsc-link-attributes/bsc:link-usage":
    Condition "boolean(count(../../../nd:link) = 1)" must be true
```

**Question: Why would boolean(count(../../../nd:link) = 1) not evaluate to true ?**

There is clearly one link in there. So what am I missing here ?

**Other validations done**

I did use the [XPath Expression Testbed](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) to come up with a pointer what I am missing, but that tool gave me the expected result. Both in the case where I verified without a context node and the case where I set the context node to the **link-usage** node in the above XML file.

Does anyone have any pointers to what I am missing ?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo? Your check refers to `nd:link` and your XML contains `nt:link`...

Comment: Hello Marcus, thanks a lot for the pointer. I did try it with the "nt:" namespace as well, only to get the dreaded "undefined prefix" XPath error. You helped me a lot though with your question: It was indeed the case that the 'nd:link' was wrong. While the syntatic validation was OK, Schematron did not use the 'nt' prefix, but the 'lnk' namespace which was the prefix defined in the 'network-topology.yang' file. So once I changed the prefix in teh must() statement to 'lnk' Schematron was happy. My conclusion: Don't change the prefix of an included yang file.

Comment: I would accept your answer as helpful, Marcus.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add boolean. Just "count(../../../nd:link) = 1" should work.